# spark-dataframe pivot missing columns/values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pivot, missing-data, dynamic-columns

Right now I'm facing a problem that I can't solve, let me explain.

I need to pivot a spark-dataframe, but in some cases there are no records for the pivot to include the column that I need. Here is an example:

Let's say that the are 4 types of events: A, B, C, D

I receive an event logs files like this:

```
|Id|year|type|
|--|----|----|
|a |2015|   A|
|a |2016|   A|
|a |2015|   A|
|a |2017|   A|
|b |2015|   A|
|b |2015|   B|
|b |2016|   D|
|b |2015|   B|
|b |2017|   A|
```

When I do the pivot I get:

```
|id|year|   A|   B|   D|
|--|----|----|----|----|
|a |2015|   2|null|null|
|a |2016|   1|null|null|
|a |2017|   1|null|null|
|b |2015|   1|   2|null|
|b |2016|   1|null|   1|
|b |2017|   1|null|null|
```

what I really need is:

```
|id|year|   A|   B|   C|   D|
|--|----|----|----|----|----|
|a |2015|   2|   0|   0|   0|
|a |2016|   1|   0|   0|   0|
|a |2017|   1|   0|   0|   0|
|b |2015|   1|   2|   0|   0|
|b |2016|   1|   0|   0|   1|
|b |2017|   1|   0|   0|   0|
```

And imagine that on each event log file that I receive there are different type events missing, but I always need to have the columns for all of the event types (A, B, C and D).

I hope that I explained myself well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val lscol = Seq((“A”),(“B”),(“C”),(“D”)).toDF(“Type”)

//df is the initial dataframe prior to pivot
df.join(lscol,df.col(“Type”)===lscol.col(“Type”),”right”)
    .drop(df(“Type”))
    .groupBy(“ID”,”year”)
    .pivot(“Type”)
    .agg(count(“Type”))
    .filter(!col(“ID”).isNull && !col(“year”).isNull)
    .na
    .fill(0)
    .show
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! So rry for the delay, I was out of the country with no internet. I'll keep you updated!